# Изменение enum в java

Tags: java, рефлексия, enum

У меня есть некий enum с несколькими значениями

```
enum MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2;
}
```

Могу ли я его изменить без изменения кода? Например при помощи Reflection.

Я пытался получить доступ к enum но ничего не вышло (я пытался при помощи Reflection)

Comment: Если у Вас возникла такая необходимость, то скорее всего Вы делаете что-то не так. Перечисления нельзя изменить во время выполнения, т.к. по сути это константы. Может быть Вы более полно опишите Вашу задачу/проблему и в этом случае можно будет найти более правильное решение.

Comment: Нельзя, но почему бы не HashMap с константами?

Comment: Я пишу модификацию для игры, и мне в идеале хотелось бы изменить enum что бы не переписываться ui

Comment: Да, содержимое енума можно изменить при помощи рефлексии, см. ответы к вопросу 2018 г. на основном SO: [In Java is it possible to change or modify an enum itself and thus to corrupt an enum singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223636/)

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enum** значение в Java неизменяемо, поэтому их нельзя изменить непосредственно с помощью рефлексии. **Enum** значения обычно рассматриваются как *константы* и не предоставляют публичных методов для изменения их состояния.

Когда вы объявляете enum в **Java**, компилятор создает класс, который *расширяет* класс **java.lang.Enum**. **Enum** значения представляют экземпляры этого класса, и они не предоставляют публичных методов для изменения своего состояния.